# How to update default value (frontend_label to DB) attribute programmaticaly Magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I want to edit the frontend label attribute. 
I know how to do this through the database, but I haven’t found anything on the Internet how to change the attribute name

[image]

How do I change the attribute name programmatically ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a data patch or an upgrade script. I'm leaving an example here.
You can run them with `bin/magento setup:upgrade` or `bin/magento setup:db-data:upgrade`

```
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vulpea\InternshipEav\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;

/**
 * Class UpdateOne
 * @package Vulpea\InternshipEav\Setup\Patch\Data
 * @author Victor Todoran <victor.todoran@yahoo.com>
 */
class UpdateOne implements DataPatchInterface
{
    const ATTRIBUTE_CODE = 'test';
    const FIELD = 'frontend_label';
    const VALUE = 'This value was set via update';

    /**
     * @var EavSetup
     */
    private $eavSetup;

    public function __construct(
        EavSetup $eavSetup
    ) {
        $this->eavSetup = $eavSetup;
    }
    /**
     * Get array of patches that have to be executed prior to this.
     *
     * example of implementation:
     *
     * [
     *      \Vendor_Name\Module_Name\Setup\Patch\Patch1::class,
     *      \Vendor_Name\Module_Name\Setup\Patch\Patch2::class
     * ]
     *
     * @return string[]
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Get aliases (previous names) for the patch.
     *
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Run code inside patch
     * If code fails, patch must be reverted, in case when we are speaking about schema - than under revert
     * means run PatchInterface::revert()
     *
     * If we speak about data, under revert means: $transaction->rollback()
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        $this->eavSetup->updateAttribute(
              \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
              self::ATTRIBUTE_CODE,
              self::FIELD,
                self::VALUE
        );
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// attributeId: you want update attribute id
$attributeModel = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
          ->get(\Magento\Eav\Model\Attribute::class)->load($attributeId);
$customAttributeValue = "you need custom attribute value";
$attributeModel->setData('frontend_label',$customAttributeValue);
$attributeModel->save();
```